# Spring data, Oracle DB, java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my application (Oracle DB[11g], Spring data, Java 8) i mapped my entity with an ID like this:

```
@Column(name = "MYID")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_SEQUENCE")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "MY_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1, name = "MY_SEQUENCE")
private Integer     id;
```

In the oracle column the type is NUMBER(38,0)

For some data when i try to findById, the application throws: SQL Error: 17026, SQLState: null - Numeric Overflow.

I tried changing the type of my java entity like long, BigDecimal and BigInteger, but i receive a convert Integer exception from Hibernate.

I can't change the definition of the table on the database.

How can resolve that problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is the code/query you're excuting, what is the complete and exact error stack trace?

Comment: Your problem is: max `Integer` is 2147483647 but max `NUMBER(38,0)` 99999999999999999999999999999999999999

Comment: Hi Marmite Bomber, ok, but which java type i can use? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never you an `Integer` data type if your database column data type is defined as `NUMBER(38,0)`, as this format may store much larger numbers than the single precision `Integer`.

More secure is to use `Long`, which covers double precision integers. To see if your data are in range covered by `Long` perform this query  (substitute table and column names)

```
select AGE from author_tab 
where not (-power(2,63) <= AGE and AGE <= power(2,63)-1)
```

If no data are returned you are on the safe side of `Long`

As a last resort use the [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) which you can trim exact to your database data type

```
@Column(precision=38, scale=0)
BigInteger age
```